# Abrir dropdown sem ele ser uma tag filha

Tags: css, dropdown

Bom dia galera, teria como criar um dropdown sem ele precisar ser uma tag filha?

Vou explicar com código. Geralmente fazemos assim:

```css
.menu-dropdown {display: none;list-style: none;}
.menu:hover .menu-dropdown {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Teste</a>
        <ul class="menu-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Abriu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Teria como fazer isso com a ul(menu-dropdown) fora da ul(menu)?

Por exemplo:

```css
.menu-dropdown {display: none;list-style: none;}
.menu:hover .menu-dropdown {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Teste</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu-dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Abriu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Como podem ver, ali não deu certo, mas, teria como fazer isso?

Comment: Apena com CSS ou vale com jQuery?

Comment: Só com CSS, com JQuery acho que ja até criei, mas, como to tentando usar o menos de JS possível, acho que seria o ideal só com CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode fazer o `:hover` em um irmão e estilizar o irmão de baixo usando o seletor `+` assim vc faz o `hover` no `.menu` e com o **+** vc diz que o irmão deve ficar com `display:block`

Depois vc precisa dizer que o `:hover` no irmão tb deve deixa-lo como `display:block`, ou então quando vc sair de um irmão para o outro o `.drop-down` vai sumir.

Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo:

```css
.menu-dropdown {display: none;list-style: none;}
.menu:hover + .menu-dropdown {display: block;} 
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.menu:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.menu-dropdown {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.menu-dropdown:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Teste</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu-dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Abriu</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

## DICA

Devido o **Box-Model** do CSS o `:hover` na *margem* do elemento não funciona, porém o `:hover` no `padding` do elemento funciona. Então no casso desse menu eu precisei remover as *margens*, e separar os irmãos com `padding`. Caso contrário se tiver uma margem entre um irmão e outro quando o mouse passar sobre essa margem o irmão `.drop-down` vai sumir... https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box_model